# Java JFrame is not exactly sized

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jframe, paint

I am trying to program a game, but I can't make exactly the big window I need.
First println gives me 720 and second 732 and the window is really bigger than 720.
How can I make the game display exactly 720 pixels high?

xCopterGame.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class xCopterGame extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  Board panel=null;
  public xCopterGame(){
    panel = new Board();
    setTitle("Pong");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,720));
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);

    System.out.println(panel.getHeight());

    panel.yCopter = getHeight()/2-15;

    panel.addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseListener(this);
  }

  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    panel.mousePressed(e);
  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    panel.mouseReleased(e);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new xCopterGame();
  }


  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

  }
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

  }
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

  }
}
```

Board.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel implements Runnable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  Thread th=null;
  boolean mousePressed = false, firstClick = false;
  int yCopter;

  public Board(){
    th = new Thread(this);
    th.start();
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.black);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(80, yCopter, 30, 30);

    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    for(int i=0; i<37; i++){
      g.drawLine(0, i*20, this.getWidth(), i*20);
    }

    g.fillRect(100, 715, 30, 5);
    g.fillRect(100, 0, 30, 5);       
    System.out.println(this.getHeight());
  }

  public void run() {
    while(true){
      if(mousePressed == true)
        yCopter--;
      if(mousePressed == false && firstClick == true)
        yCopter++;

   //   repaint();

      try { 
        Thread.sleep(10); 
      } 
      catch(InterruptedException ex) {

      }
    }
  }

  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    mousePressed = true;
    firstClick = true;
  }
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    mousePressed = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(10);`  Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

`setResizable()` may affect insets of the frame. It is best to call pack() after `setResizable()`. Try this order of calls:

```
setResizable(false);
pack();
setVisible(true);
```

For reference, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14988318/1048330) analysis by @HovercraftFullOfEels

You may also find [Should I avoid the use of set[Preferred|Maximum|Minimum]Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/1048330) helpful.

Comment: +1 Nice, I always forget this (but then again, I don't like non-resiable frames ;))

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, exactly, same here :)

Answer (score 0):

I could notice you are just setting up the `Board` prefered size. If you want to force a specific size for your window, you can simply call the method `JFrame.setSize()` of you `xCopterGame`.

I encorage you to take a look at this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/problems.html). There are other ways to implement a Swing UI without having to deal with this kind of problem when you use a `LayoutManager`.

Comment: Windows have boarders and other content which is "squeezed" into the frames bounds, meaning the content space is then smaller the expected.  What the OP is doing is actually correct.  Set the preferred size of the content and let the frame add it's stuff to the outside, so the resulting frame size should be larger then the preferred size of the content.  I think Aqua hit the nail on the head

Comment: Agree with @MadProgrammer - this is just going the wrong way.  -1 for first paragraph, +1 for the second for referencing a Java Tutorial link re. layout managers.  Net 0.